Legends are not refreshed after applying filter in Google Charts
on Load Chart loaded like

After applying selectable and on the click of Reset button(X at end)
Chart looks like this

I have three values in the Selectable

North
South
East

On selecting North, chart is filtering properly with the data, on the click of Reset button Legends are not sorted to its original position. Instead North gets appended in the Legend twice.
Pasting my code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <base target="_top">  
    <?!= include('page_style'); ?> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="st_accordion">
    <h3>    
      <span>State&nbsp;</span>
      <button class="button-reset ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" title="Reset">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
      </button>
    </h3>
    <div><ul class="st_selectable"></ul></div>
    </div>     
    <div id="chart_st_pdiv" class="chart_container1"></div> 
</body>

CSS Code:
.st_accordion > div.ui-accordion-content {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
.st_selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.st_selectable li {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8pt;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
}
.st_selectable .ui-selecting {
  background-color: #99ccff;
    border: 1px solid #809fff;
}
.st_selectable .ui-selected {
  background-color: #007fff;
    border: 1px solid #003eff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-button-icon-only {
  float: right;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0px;
  min-width: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ui-widget {
  font-size: 8pt;
}

JS Script:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/> 
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var click = 0;

function filter_st_charts(){
      var st_chartview={};
      var st_selectedvalues = [];

      var r_row;
      var r_view = {
            columns: [0]
        };      

      $('.st_selectable li.ui-selected').each(function(index, selected) {        
        st_selectedvalues.push(selected.innerHTML);
      });

      

      if(st_selectedvalues.length > 0){
                              
        for (var i = 0; i < st_selectedvalues.length; i++) {            
          r_row = r_columnTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: st_selectedvalues[i]}])[0];
          r_view.columns.push(r_columnTable.getValue(r_row, 0));
        }        
      }
r_view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
          return (a - b);
      });

      st_chart.setView(r_view);
      st_chart.draw();
    }

onload_st_filter_values = st_initState.selectedValues;
google.visualization.events.addListener(st_chart,'ready',function() {
      var filt_values = onload_st_filter_values;
      console.log("Inside ready");
      if(click==0){
        $.each(filt_values.filter(uniquelists), function(index, value) {
        $('.st_selectable').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
        });
      }
      
    $('.st_accordion').accordion({
      active: false,
      create: function () {
        $('.st_selectable').selectable({
          filter: '*',
          stop: filter_st_charts
        });
      },
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: 'content'
    });

    $('.button-reset').button();    
    $('.button-reset').on('click', clearFilter);

    click++

    })

function clearFilter(sender) {
      console.log("Inside Clear Filter");
      var accordion;
      sender.preventDefault();
      sender.stopPropagation();

      accordion = $(sender.target).closest('.st_accordion');
      accordion.find('.st_selectable li').removeClass('st_selectable .ui-selected');
      accordion.accordion('option', 'active', false);     
      filter_st_charts();
      return false;
  }
</script>

